# php foreach. select specific value from array and use it as parameter for display loop

Tags: php, session, loops, foreach

I want to be able to display titles of the books of the author who is currently logged in. I'm using PHP session

```
<? foreach ($books as $book ): ?>

<? foreach ($book as $selbook => $author): ?>
    <option value="$selbook>"$author['author'] == $_SESSION["sess_username"] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>> $author?></option>

<li class="active"><a href=""><span class="pull-right"><input id="button" type="submit" name="submitr" value="Edit"></span><i class="icon-fire$
<? echo htmlspecialchars($book['Title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> <strong> - </strong><em>
<? echo htmlspecialchars($book['author'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></em></a></li>
<? endforeach; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. Clean it up. Remove <?= . Use foreach(): endforeach; for both foreaches. Make sure that your html tags open and close. Use variables and then echo them after.

Comment: yeah. I know, sorry for that. I just started studying this. Wasn't able to clean it up before posting

anyway, how can I fix the display loop?

this is my first post here in stackoverflow. thanks for the quick comment

Answer (score 0):

You start 2nd foreach with this:

```
<?php foreach ($book as $selbook => $author) { ?>
```

And end with this:

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It is not correct. Use this:

```
<?php foreach ($book as $selbook => $author): ?>
    // some code
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, why u use `<?php`? Short tag is not enabled? Use `<?` it is much faster to write and code is more readable. Also, when you want to echo some variable, using php tag use this:

```
<?=$variable;?>
```

Much faster and more readable too.

### Update

Try this:

```
<? foreach ($books as $book ): ?>
 <? foreach ($book as $selbook => $author): ?>
  <option value="<?=$selbook;?>" <? if($author['author'] == $_SESSION["sess_username"]): ?>selected="selected"<? endif; ?> ><?=$author;?></option>

  <li class="active"><a href=""><span class="pull-right"><input id="button" type="submit"  name="submitr" value="Edit"></span><i class="icon-fire$
  <? echo htmlspecialchars($book['Title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> <strong> - </strong><em>
  <? echo htmlspecialchars($book['author'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></em></a></li>
 <? endforeach; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks. I think my problem is not how i wrote the tags but on my <option value ... > syntax. can you help me with that? I'm not really familiar with php foreach loop. thanks for the answer though